# Android: Add images via java code

Tags: android, image, parsing, textview

i'm trying to display an image called phone.png before a textView via java. Let me explain better.

```
    ((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText(new StringBuilder(timeFormat.format(new Date(date))).append(DASH).append(context.getString(SimpleParser.getTranslatedParserName(filename))));
    return view;
}
```

**This part of code will parse for files in a predefined directory and display the results as
CURRENTTIME - FILEPREFIX**

So, assuming the script is just looking 4 FILEPREFIX (test1_12456.zip test2_12456.zip test3_12456.zip test4_12456.zip) is it possible to display right before "CURRENTTIME" an image assigned to each prefix? If prefix is test1 the result will be:
Test1Image CURRENTTIME - TEST1

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could add the textview to a tablerow. Before you add the textview you could add an imageView and do something like :

```
imageView.setIcon(someImage);
```

It would look like :

```
<TableLayout>
    <TableRow>
        <ImageView />
        <TextView />
    <TableRow>
<TableLayout>
```

And you could add tableRows dynamically.